# Find web sites address in my folder files with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i have a bunch of html files in a folde of my pc and i would love to find all the web sites address like 
http://www.stackoverflow.com
or
http://stackoverflow.com
or
www.stackoverflow.com

Someon can help me to do the right expression?

I tried the following, but it does not work :

```
.*?(http\:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what RegexBuddy uses to check.

```
(\b(https?|ftp|file)://)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]
```

It matches these below (inside the ** ** marks):

```
**http://www.regexbuddy.com**  
**http://www.regexbuddy.com/**  
**http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html**  
**http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html?source=library**
```

I found this blog quite useful, you should probably check it out:

http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/